# debug running windows containers deployed in Azure Kubernetes service

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, windows-container

I have a multi node pool cluster setup in Azure Kubernetes service. linux node pool and windows node pool. I also have 2 containers deployed in a single pod on the windows node pool (since the application is built on .net frameowrk ). My containers are up and running however i wanted to know if there is a way to debug these containers while they are running. Tools found online are inclined towards linux node pool or .net core. It is going to take some time to convert code to .net core since we still have legacy WCF stuff.

is there a way or a tool (3rd party or via VS 2019 ) where i can connect to the cluster and debug the containers in the windows node pool. (Azure Dev Spaces also are inclined towards linux node pool unless i taint the windows node pool).

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem since we're planning to migrate to AKS and have some Windows legacy stuff that we would like to move to AKS Windows nodes, as far as I know Dev Spaces only works with Linux based pods and right now the only option to debug Windows ones is to use the Visual Studio snapshot debugger but we've not yet tried this road in AKS.